# Replace all occurences of \n\r from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

I need to replace a `\n\r` from a string multiple times. I managed to replace the first occurrence, but it doesn't work for more than one time. Something is not right with the escaping. I've tried:

```
$ node
> 'string\n\rstring\n\r'.replace('\n\r', '');
'stringstring\n\r'
> 'string\n\rstring\n\r'.replace('/\n\r/g', '');
'string\n\rstring\n\r'
> 'string\n\rstring\n\r'.replace('/\\n\\r/g', '');
'string\n\rstring\n\r'
> 'string\n\rstring\n\r'.replace('/\\\n\\\r/g', '');
'string\n\rstring\n\r'
> 'string\n\rstring\n\r'.replace('/\\\\n\\\\r/g', '');
'string\n\rstring\n\r'
```

How do I get `stringstring`?

Comment: Use your second solution, just as a regex literal: `.replace(/\n\r/g, '')`, although the usual Windows style line break char sequence is `\r\n`.

Comment: Right it was `\r\n`. Ok so the error was to put the regex into ticks (`' '`). If you put your comment in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: There is no need for an answer, it is a very common typo.

Comment: The `\r\n` sequence can easily be remembered by the meaning behind them. First place the cursor back at the start at the of the line (carriage return) then move a line down (line feed).